# Multiple Select Field in flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to use multiselectfield to move data from left to right with flask. I can display and move datas from left to right easily but when I submit the form, I have error saying that field doesn't have valid choises.

Am I doing as well as it could ? There is another way to do it ?

This is my code :

forms.py:

```py
class MigrateUsersForm(FlaskForm):
    multiselect = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs des anciennes campagne")
    multiselect_to = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs de la campagne en cours")
    submit = SubmitField('Valider')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MigrateUsersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.multiselect.choices = [(s.id, s.nom_agent+" "+s.prenoms_agent) for s in (User.query.filter(User.id!=current_user.id, User.id.in_(db.session.query(Users_Campagne.users_id).join(Campagnes).filter(Users_Campagne.campagne_id==Campagnes.campagne_id, Campagnes.isActive==0))).order_by(User.nom_agent).all())]
        self.multiselect_to.choices = [(s.id, s.nom_agent+" "+s.prenoms_agent) for s in (User.query.filter(User.id!=current_user.id, User.id.in_(db.session.query(Users_Campagne.users_id).join(Campagnes).filter(Users_Campagne.campagne_id==Campagnes.campagne_id, Campagnes.isActive==1))).order_by(User.nom_agent).all())]
```

template.html:

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="" autocomplete="off">
                    {{ form.csrf_token }}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label for="multiselect" class="col-form-label">Anciens utilisateurs *</label>
                                    {{ form.multiselect(size=10, class='form-control',  multiple="multiple") }}
                                    <span style="color: #f00"> {% if form.multiselect.errors %}{{ form.multiselect.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 7%;">
                                <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-forward3"></span></button>
                                <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-cheveron-right"></span></button>
                                <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-cheveron-left"></span></button>
                                <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-backward2"></span></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                                <div class="form-group ">
                                    <label for="multiselect_to" class="col-form-label">Nouveau utilisateurs *</label>
                                    {{ form.multiselect_to(size=10, class='form-control',  multiple="multiple") }}
                                    <span style="color: #f00"> {% if form.multiselect_to.errors %}{{ form.multiselect_to.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-right">
                           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

views.py

```py
@login_required
def migrate_users():
    form = MigrateUsersForm()
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        print("Here am i")
        '''multiselect = ', '.join(form.multiselect.data)
        multiselect_to = ', '.join(form.multiselect_to.data)
        print(multiselect)
        print(multiselect_to)'''
    return render_template('admin/migrate_users.html', form=form)
```

This how template is displayed
[image: Template on load]

When i select element from left to right, i have this 
[image: When I moves elements from left to right]

And when I click on validate, this is error I face
[Error I face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UIqS.jpg)

Comment: Include necessary code of the routes where you submit the form.

Comment: I added code of the route @arsho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have replaced `self.multiselect.choices` and `self.multiselect_to.choices` with fixed list of values and can get the selected multiple values in submitted `POST` request.

Directory structure:

```
├── multi_select_app.py
├── multi_select_form.py
└── templates
    └── multi_select.html
```

`multi_select_app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from multi_select_form import MigrateUsersForm

app = Flask(__name__)
# Set the secret key to some random bytes. Keep this really secret!
app.secret_key = b'_5#y2L"F4Q8z\n\xec]/'

@app.route('/migrate', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def migrate_users():
    form = MigrateUsersForm()
    if request.method == "POST" and form.validate_on_submit():
        multiselect = ', '.join(form.multiselect.data)
        multiselect_to = ', '.join(form.multiselect_to.data)
        posted_data = {
            "multiselect": multiselect,
            "multiselect_to": multiselect_to
        }
        return jsonify(posted_data)
    return render_template('multi_select.html', form=form)
```

`multi_select_form.py`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectMultipleField, SubmitField

class MigrateUsersForm(FlaskForm):
    multiselect = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs des anciennes campagne")
    multiselect_to = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs de la campagne en cours")
    submit = SubmitField('Valider')


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MigrateUsersForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.multiselect.choices = [("py", "python"), ("rb", "ruby"), ("js", "javascript")]
        self.multiselect_to.choices = [("py", "python"), ("rb", "ruby"), ("js", "javascript")]
```

`templates\multi_select.html`:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="" autocomplete="off">
  {{ form.csrf_token }}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="multiselect" class="col-form-label">Anciens utilisateurs *</label>
        {{ form.multiselect(size=10, class='form-control',  multiple="multiple") }}
        <span style="color: #f00"> {% if form.multiselect.errors %}{{ form.multiselect.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 7%;">
      <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-forward3"></span></button>
      <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-cheveron-right"></span></button>
      <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-cheveron-left"></span></button>
      <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><span class="icon-backward2"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="multiselect_to" class="col-form-label">Nouveau utilisateurs *</label>
        {{ form.multiselect_to(size=10, class='form-control',  multiple="multiple") }}
        <span style="color: #f00"> {% if form.multiselect_to.errors %}{{ form.multiselect_to.errors[0] }}{% endif %}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Valider</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

`requirements.txt` (installed packages):

```
aniso8601==6.0.0
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.7
Flask-REST-JSONAPI==0.26.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.7
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
marshmallow==2.18.0
marshmallow-jsonapi==0.21.0
pytz==2018.9
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.2
Werkzeug==0.15.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

Running the application:

```
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_APP=multi_select_app.py
flask run
```

**Output:**

Multi select Input form (missing CSS files so broken style):

[image: input form]

Submitted values after clicking submit button:

[image: submitted values]

As you can see, we are getting the correct multiple selected values after form submission.
Please check the `self.multiselect.choices` and `self.multiselect_to.choices` values in `__init__` method of `MigrateUsersForm` form.

**Update:** 
I think `s.id` is an integer field. When you submit the form it is being treated as a string field. Set `coerce=int` in `SelectMultipleField`. 
Replace both:

- `multiselect = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs des anciennes campagne")` with `multiselect = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs des anciennes campagne", coerce=int)`
- `multiselect_to = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs de la campagne en cours")` with `multiselect_to = SelectMultipleField("Utilisateurs de la campagne en cours", coerce=int)`

**Reference:**
- [SelectMultipleField Documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=fields.selectfield#wtforms.fields.SelectMultipleField)

Comment: Maybe i haven't explained my problem correctly. The left selectfield has values and right one is empty. I want to use buttons to take element from left to right or right to left. And when an element moves to a side, it's removed from the list it is coming from.

Comment: You can move the values from one list to another using JavaScript / jQuery. As you are using `SelectMultipleField`, you need to select the values before clicking on the `Valider` button.

Comment: I use jQuery to move values from list to another one. Look at the images on my first post. Maybe you will understand better what I want to do.

Comment: I think `s.id` is an integer field. See the update in the answer.

Comment: Finally i solve my problem by using `jQuery multiselect plugin`